# How can I animate an ionic icon

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to make this icon move but so far had no luck doing this. Does anyone know how I can make this icon flicker or something?

```
<i id="informationCommentIcon" class="icon ion-fireball assertive "></i>
<a id="informationCommentText" ng-click="promoFunction()">Promo Deal</a>
```

Comment: animating something needs javascript or CSS(animate). luckily there is "animate.css" you may love. check https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ and, add some classes that you want with ng-class when ng-click is clicked. If you need more help, please let us know with your sample code.

Comment: `<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="animated rotateIn"> content</div>
    </body>
    </html>`

Comment: Thank you! Using this method it seems to do nothing?? Is this restricted from hybrid apps? (cordova)

Comment: It's pure CSS.Doesn't matter whatever you use (cordova or something) if the browser supports CSS.